# How to count the number of bank accounts that belong to one user in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a few questions regarding the use of GROUP BY in SQL,

How do you count the number of open bank accounts that belong to one specific user?
I tried to write the most correct sentence possible so that the SQL could count all the associated accounts of each user, instead the result is somewhat easy? It just shows 1s in all the queries...

```
SELECT DISTINCT RPAD(CLI.NOMBRE || '  ' ||CLI.APELLIDOS,30) "Nombre y Apellidos",
                SUM(CUE.SALDO) "Saldo", COUNT(CUE.COD_CUENTA) "Cuentas Abiertas"
from CLIENTE CLI,
     CUENTA CUE
WHERE CLI.COD_CLIENTE = CUE.COD_CLIENTE
GROUP BY CLI.NOMBRE, CLI.APELLIDOS, CUE.SALDO, CUE.COD_CUENTA
```

In my case, I tried looking for users with name and surnames and also count the accounts that users have opened, instead, the query repeats names and the "Counter" shows 1s as result

[Result][1] ;
[The E/R Diagram][2]

Thanks in advance!!!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDac.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlVte.png

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `SALDO` and `COD_CUENTA` and that prevents traditional aggregation counts to show the result you want.

However, you can use a window function: you need to tell the `COUNT()` function about the scope it needs to operate adding `OVER(PARTITION BY cli.cod_cliente)`.

For example:

```
select distinct 
  rpad(cli.nombre || '  ' || cli.apellidos, 30) as "nombre y apellidos",
  sum(cue.saldo) as "saldo",
  count(cue.cod_cuenta) over(partition by cli.cod_cliente) as "cuentas abiertas"
from cliente cli
join cuenta cue on cli.cod_cliente = cue.cod_cliente
group by cli.nombre, cli.apellidos, cue.saldo, cue.cod_cuenta
```

**NOTE**: Please use modern join syntax, not those joins from the 80s. I updated your query.

Comment: Thank you very much! In terms of joins, these are syntaxes I'm being taught at school, so I didn't really know there would be more "modern" ways to write a query, I'll keep it in mind though, and will improve on my writing if that's the case :)

Comment: @AliSadykov What school? I'm surprised they still teach technology from the 80s.

Comment: Well, it's a Spanish school in Barcelona, they offer vocational education so that people like me could find a job in specific area of expertise, tho I never knew that the way we write those syntaxes were from Chen's era, so there's that, but I have a feeling that my teacher knows that already, but since JOINS are easy to write that way he though we could use them without any issues, the fact that SQL developer permits us to write 'old-style' and DBeaver doesn't, confuses me and my classmates a bit

Comment: @AliSadykov All good. Just a note. Some interviewers may look at that syntax as outdated.